# Jump starting when boot is locked Volvo bifuel v70

Tags: volvo, jump-start, v70

I can't jump start my Volvo V70 as my boot is locked.I have been told that I can jumpstart it on the engine ,but where? Battery is in the boot..it's a  bifuel estate.

Comment: What year is your V70?

Answer (score 2):

Here is where the jump points are for your V70:

Positive jump point is located behind the fuse box by the strut tower:

[image]

The negative jump point is located to the right side of the engine (as if sitting in the driver's seat) where you can see the clamp on the metal loop:

[image]

Attache them in this order (per Volvo):

[image]